# Abstract Exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to define a set of base exceptions that can only subclass, but having trouble getting python to actually enforce a class's abstractness.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyExec(ABC, Exception):
    @abstractmethod
    def func():
        pass

MyExec()
```

I'm expecting this to raise something like:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyExec with abstract methods func
```

However in reality it just works and doesn't error.

Digging deeper this looks like a method resolution order issue.

```
(Pdb) MyExec.__mro__
(<class '__main__.MyExec'>, <class 'abc.ABC'>, <class 'Exception'>, <class 'BaseException'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Looks like `abc.ABC` is first and looks like [`ABC.__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/abc.py#L127) is where the magic happens to actually enforce abstractness. So I'm assuming there is some funky rules between `ABC.__new__` (under the hood it's actually `ABCMeta.__new__`) and `Exception.__new__`.

```
(Pdb) MyExec.__new__ == ABC.__new__
False
(Pdb) MyExec.__new__ == Exception.__new__
True
```

Anyone know how to override this ordering or am I doing something I shouldn't be here? Surprisingly found very little searching on this.

EDIT: I solved this by implementing the solution suggested [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue5996#msg266704). Looks like it's a core bug but they haven't decided if it's a documentation or implementation bug and provided that workaround in the meantime.

Comment: All you have to do to reverse the order of MRO is change the order in the class declaration, i.e. `class MyExec(Exception, ABC)`, but does not seem to make a difference...

Comment: There was a similar question recently. As far as I can tell, trying to mark children of built-in types (for some definition of "built-in" that is specific enough to exclude `object`, anyway) with `ABC` simply does not work.

Comment: @zvone yeah tried reversing the order, it looks like `ABCMeta.__new__` is just never called (I haven't dug into the execution to double check but guessing `Exception.__new__` doesn't call `super`).

Comment: @AlexLatchford `ABCMeta.__new__` is called regardless of the order of inheritance. That is a metaclass after all, not one of the base classes. In the end, `ABCMeta.__new__` ends up calling [`_abc_init._abc_init(MyExec)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/028f0ef4f3111d2b3fc5b971642e337ba7990873/Lib/abc.py#L127) which does the trick. Or, apparently, does not do the trick, if you inherit from Exception.

Comment: Looks like you can achieve the behaviour by implementing this: https://bugs.python.org/issue5996#msg266704

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of the ones linked above.